# Flutter Firebase get several collections from all parents documents

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, stream

How do I find all the "products" for all my "stores" in a stream (so not only one specific store)?

Here is the code:

```
return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
            stream: Firestore.instance.collection('users').document(uid).collection('stores')
                .document(storeID).collection('products').snapshots(),
            builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) { 
              ...
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get **all** of the documents among **all** subcollections with the name "products", then you will want to use a [collection group query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query).

```
Firestore.instance.collectionGroup('products').snapshots()
```